# How to avoid repetition of CSS properties across multiple Web Components

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm building with Web Component without any 3rd-party framework.

And I have vanilla `<button>` in several of my components, and I have to reset EVERY ONE of them before I do my custom styling on them because resetting it once at a root level doesn't work since the properties involved are not one of inheritable styles that pierce through shadow dom:

```
button {
   appearance: none;
   background: none;
   border: none;
   ...
}
```

What do you all think is the current best and widely supported way to avoid this repetition?

I have looked at the [Constructable Stylesheets](https://web.dev/constructable-stylesheets/), but it's poorly supported in Firefox, which is my main browser. I also considered CSS Custom Properties, but that would still lead to repetition of `background`, `border` etc. properties everywhere right?

Comment: Does this help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all ?

Comment: Seems [only works](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/upbeat-brindle-cartoon?path=index.html%3A49%3A4) on inheritable styles.

Comment: *and since only font related CSS can pierce through shadow dom* That is wrong. What "pierces" shadow DOM is only CSS inheritance, that is, inherited properties (and that's a very good thing!).

Comment: There has been experimental support for constructable stylesheets in Firefox since version 73 (Feb. 2020). Not sure why it hasn't changed the experimental feature status for more than 2 years now. You can enable it by setting `layout.css.constructable-stylesheets.enabled` to `true` in `about:config`.

Comment: Does end-users have to do the same in `about:config` as well?

Comment: See my answer below, there's a polyfill available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructable stylesheets are designed to address, among others, exactly this problem you're having.

There has been [experimental support for constructable stylesheets in Firefox since version 73 (Feb. 2020)](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_cssstylesheet_cssstylesheet). Not sure why it hasn't left the experimental feature status for more than 2 years now.

You can enable it by setting `layout.css.constructable-stylesheets.enabled` to `true` in `about:config`.

Until it's no longer experimental, you can use a [polyfill](https://github.com/calebdwilliams/construct-style-sheets#readme).

The next thing that will help you reduce redundancy is called [CSS Module Scripts](https://web.dev/css-module-scripts/). From that page:

> Deduplication: if the same CSS file is imported from multiple places in an application, it will still only be fetched, instantiated, and parsed a single time.

Unfortunately, that also hasn't landed in Firefox yet (see this [tracking bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1720570)), but already [in the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#creating-a-css-module-script).

Comment: Thank you! I will use the polyfill for now. luckily its file size is [quite small](https://bundlephobia.com/package/construct-style-sheets-polyfill@3.1.0).

Answer (score -1):

But if i say to [tailwind css](https://tailwindcss.com/) with reactjs. Reactjs specially designed to remove repetition.
Please check tailwind docs where even you can assign your custom css function for anything.

Comment: You did not understand the question. Tailwind, while also being the worst possible approach in my opinion, is not of great help when it comes to web components and shadow DOM.

Comment: According to me any approach that will help to solve any query is best. That is why am telling about tailwind.